# What's new in python 3.7 about circular imports?

Tags: python, python-3.7

This is a point from python 3.7 changelog.

> bpo-30024: Circular imports involving absolute imports with binding a submodule to a name are now supported.

What is the example of code that wouldn't work in 3.6 but works now?

Comment: Just look at the discussion on [b.p.o](https://bugs.python.org/issue30024)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Issue 30024](https://bugs.python.org/issue30024) discusses the problem and the patch.  But I did not find it immediately helpful.  It does mention that getting a proper, comprehensible test example would be a major step.

The [patch](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/f93234bb8a87855f295d441524e519481ce6ab13) added the following:

In  Lib/test/test_import/data/circular_imports/binding.py:

```
import test.test_import.data.circular_imports.binding2 as binding2
```

In  Lib/test/test_import/data/circular_imports/binding2.py:

```
import test.test_import.data.circular_imports.binding as binding
```

Two submodules of a module import each other as some name.  Here is the test that presumably failed before:

```
def test_binding(self):
    try:
        import test.test_import.data.circular_imports.binding
    except ImportError:
        self.fail('circular import with binding a submodule to a name failed')
```